# Commutativity of Direct and Inverse Limits for a special case.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In general direct and inverse limits do not commute but in some cases it does (Ref: Handbook of Categorical Algebra, Volume 1: Basic Category Theory by Francis Borceux Chapter 2). The question here concerns a specific example.

For concreteness let us work over commutative rings, so that inverse limit $\varprojlim$ preserves injection (but not surjection) and direct limit $\varinjlim$ is an exact functor. Let $A_i$ be complete (say with respect to some ideal) and thus (by assumption) $\varprojlim_\lambda A_i=A_i$. Consider the following directed system 
$$
\begin{equation}\label{one}
A_1\hookrightarrow A_2\hookrightarrow \ldots\hookrightarrow A_i\hookrightarrow\ldots\hookrightarrow \varinjlim_i A_i=\bigcup_i A_i
\end{equation}
$$

Apply inverse limit to the above and since by assumption $\varprojlim A_i=A_i$ this gives
$$
A_1\hookrightarrow A_2\hookrightarrow \ldots\hookrightarrow A_i\hookrightarrow\ldots\hookrightarrow \varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i
$$

The universal property of direct limit gives the map $\varinjlim_i A_i\rightarrow\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i$ and universal property of inverse limit gives the map $\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i\rightarrow\varinjlim_i A_i $.

**Question** Can we conclude that in the above case $\varinjlim_i A_i=\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i$? Why?
*Conditional Example* If above holds it gives an example of $\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i=\varinjlim_i\varprojlim_\lambda A_i$.

Comment: Do you mean you work in the category of modules over a fixed ring ? If so, then no, it is not implied : Take $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, which we see as $\varinjlim_n \frac{1}{p^n}\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then all these modules are clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and hence complete with respect to $(p)$, however $\mathbb{Q}_p/p^n = 0$ for all $n$ so $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not complete

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p[1/p]$ (a localization which you are expressing as direct limit). Thus, $\mathbb{Q}_p=\varinjlim_i\varprojlim_\lambda\mathbb{Z}_p$ (with $\varprojlim_\lambda\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p$). But I am asking the other direction $\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i\mathbb{Z}_p$. In both the cases the answer is $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Note that $\varprojlim_\lambda$ is projective limit.

Comment: No what I'm saying is that in the second case the answer is not $\mathbb{Q}_p$ : can you compute $\varprojlim_n \mathbb{Q}_p/p^n$ ?

Comment: Thanks!! $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is field and $p^{n}, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible, hence $\mathbb{Q}_p/p^n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Max my question is related to Tate Algebras and is posted at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3226063/673630)